# string.replace does not return the modified string in Python

Tags: python

I am trying to make an encrypting program in Python that creates a new 'key' for every use. That part works fine. The part I am having trouble with is the actual encryption. My code will not encrypt the string that the user gives. It seems to work all the way up to the for loop and I don't understand why it's not working.

```
import keycreater as k
k = k.keycreater()
print(k.key)
class encrypt(object):
    '''
    This class is used to actually encrypt the string
    '''
    def __init__(self):
        '''
        This method is used to initialize the class.
        Attributes: initial (what the user wants encrypted), new (the string after it is encrypted).
        '''
        self.initial = []
        self.new = ''
    def getstr(self):
        '''
        This method gets what the user wants to encrypt.
        Attributes: initial (what the user wants encrypted).
        '''
        self.initial = raw_input('What would you like to encrypt? ')
    def encrypt(self):
        '''
        This method takes the string that the user wants encrypted and encrypts it with a for loop.
        Attributes: alphabet (list of characters), key (key), new (encrypted string).
        '''
        alphabet = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z', '1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9']
        key = k.key
        self.new = self.initial.lower()
        for x in range(0,35):
            self.new.replace(alphabet[x],key[x])

a = encrypt()
a.getstr()
a.encrypt()
print(a.new)
```

Comment: Strings are **immutable**, `self.new.replace(alphabet[x],key[x])` will **not** change `self.new`. Try `self.new = self.new.replace(...)`. Also, consider what happens if a future replacement overlaps with a previous replacement...

Comment: Have you tried a `print` statement inside your `for` loop? `print` is your friend. Back in the day of dos and Windows 3.11, `printf` was all I had.

Answer (score 2):

Your for-loop works fine. But `string` is immutable as jonrsharpe says. Also your `for-loop and replace` will return wrong result.

You should split your string to characters and replace each character using key. After that you can use `''.join(characters)` to made new string.

```
encode_string = []
for s in user_string:
   encode_string.append(convert(s))
return ''.join(encode_string)
```

or same with `map`

`''.join(map(convert, user_string))`

Also you can import alphabet from [string](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html) module.